# What were the original lyrics to "Everyone Knows Juanita"?

Tags: coco

In the Pixar film *Coco*, when Héctor performs "*Everyone Knows Juanita*" for his friend Chicharrón, he changes one of the lines to be more family friendly.

> **Héctor:**
>   Well, everyone knows Juanita
>   Her eyes each a different color
>   Her teeth stick out and her chin goes in
>   And her...knuckles, they drag on the floor
>
> **Chicharrón:**
>   ***Those aren't the words!***
>
> **Héctor:**
>   ***There are children present***

What was the actual line that made Héctor censor himself?

Comment: We'll never know; http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/GettingCrapPastTheRadar

Comment: In Spanish it's *"her lemons are twisted round"* and in French it's "*his nails drag along the floor"*

Comment: I'm pretty sure the original word would have been slang for breasts that rhymes with spits.

Comment: @Broklynite The word "tits" is as old as the English language, hardly slang.

Comment: @user14111 dammit Jim, I'm a chemist, not an etymologist!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The most common guess I've heard is 'knockers', which makes sense since it explains why he was able to come up with 'knuckles' so quickly (still quite an achievement to improvise it on the fly, mind).

Plus, Google says that the use of that word in writing peaked around the time Héctor died, so it's a term he would have been familiar with (if he spoke English, anyway). 'Tits', which was suggested by another commenter, existed in the 1920s but only really started to get popular around the 2000s. (And it's only one syllable. So it wouldn't really fit anyway).

Comment: No doubt you're right about "knockers" because of scansion and its resemblance to "knuckles". **However:** The word "tits" has existed at least since the 1200s, and did not "start to get popular" in the 2000s; it has **always** been more popular than "knockers" which (as a slangy term for tits) only goes back to around 1940.

Comment: Yeah, "tit" is actually older than any of the non-naughty words you might use to replace it; it's an old alternate form of "teat". Though its use in the plural to refer to a human woman's breasts is only attested from about 1928, it gained popularity very quickly, and its use in the musical "Grease" (set in the 50's) is not at all anachronistic.

Answer (score 11):

Are you talking about the fictional origins of these lyrics? Because these ARE the original lyrics; "Everyone knows Juanita" is an original song written by Adrian Molina and Germaine Franco for the 2017 Pixar movie, Coco.
https://acadianasthriftymom.com/2017/11/29/the-meaning-and-love-behind-the-music-of-disneypixar-coco/ (the writing of Juanita is discussed 2/3 of the way down)
[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B073LZD7PH/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B073LZD7PH) (see back of CD cover, left lower corner for writing credits)

I too started researching the lyrics to the original Mexican song, but then it occurred to me... what if it SOUNDS like an old Mexican song but it's an original song written for the movie? Turns out they did a VERY convincing job of making it sound like an old Mexican ranchera.

I do agree with the theory that the authors probably implied "knockers" with the euphemistic "knuckles."

Comment: Yes, I think the question is what word is implied to be changed to “knuckles”, in-universe.

Answer (score 3):

The word is not nor would have been tits or knockers. Those are English language derived words. The song is Spanish in origin. The word would be of Spanish origin, therefore, probably chiches or tetas.
Someone earlier suggested "her lemons" which would translate as limoncitos or small breast. I don't think that would fit the context of the song though. Small breast dragging the floor and all....

Comment: The Spanish version of the song (from the OST) uses the phrase "Con sus uñas el suelo rayó" (with her nails she scratched the floor). I'm not very familiar with spanish slang, so I'm not sure which words could substitute here, but tetas could work (though something related to nipples might make more sense)

Answer (score 2):

I assumed the "original" word that Hector replaced was *nipples*, as the song doesn't use slang for any other body parts it describes.

Comment: Why would it be nipples? Do you have any reason to believe it was nipples?

Comment: It would be as logical as the accepted answer, similar starting consonant, slightly dirty, and fitting in an anatomical sense as sagging breasts are a common appearance slur for females, especially older ones.

Answer (score 2):

I assumed it was implied to be "tatas" - Spanish slang for "large breasts".

"Knockers" would work, but it is distinctly English in origin, and I think he was just looking for something that could "drag on the floor" to replace the word with.

Comment: I like that this answer takes into account the Spanish-language origin.

Comment: The actual Spanish version of the song (as heard in the Spanish-language edition of _Coco_, and featured on the soundtrack) has _uñas_ "fingernails". Not sure what naughty Spanish word would fit there and sound anything like that..

Comment: Tetas could replace uñas

Answer (score -2):

The original song says “*chi-chis*”, which are supposed to be interpreted as breasts.

Comment: Can you provide a source for your claim? How did you reach this conclusion?